# Remove string Item from array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array, the string and the array have same names "item", one instance is an array and the other is a string in the array, I would like to remove the entire "item" string from the array

The array;

```
//JSON



 [{
          "id":"109",
          "text":"dashboard",
          "items":[ //to be ignored
             {
                "id":"1",
                "text":"financial_dashboard",
                "items":"109" //to be deleted
             },
             {
                "id":"108",
                "text":"project_dashboard",
                "items":"109" //to be deleted
             }
          ]
       }]


//Array PHP
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 109
            [expanded] =>  true
            [text] => Dashboard
            [items] => Array  //to be ignored
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [expanded] =>  true
                            [text] => Financial Dashboard
                            [items] => 109  //to be deleted
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 108
                            [expanded] =>  true
                            [text] => Project Dashboard
                            [items] => 109  //to be deleted
                        )

                )

        ))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a JSON, right?

Comment: you must know how the array work, this multidimensional array you can delete this by delete : array[0][0], array [0][1]

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { for (j = 0; j < arr[i].items.length; j++) {arr[i].items[j].items = undefined}`

Answer (score 0):

you must know how the array work, this multidimensional array you can delete this by delete : array[0][0] and array[0][1]

```
unset($a[0][0]);
unset($a[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do with two nested maps as follows;

```js
var arr = [{
      "id":"109",
      "text":"dashboard",
      "items":[ //to be ignored
         {
            "id":"1",
            "text":"financial_dashboard",
            "items":"109" //to be deleted
         },
         {
            "id":"108",
            "text":"project_dashboard",
            "items":"109" //to be deleted
         }
      ]
   }];
   
function delNestedItems(a){
 return a.map(o => (o.items.map(q => (delete q.items,q)),o));
}

console.log(delNestedItems(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive PHP function like this one:

```
function removeItems(&$arr) {
    if (!is_array($arr)) return;
    if (isset($arr["items"]) && is_string($arr["items"])) unset($arr["items"]);
    foreach ($arr as &$value ) removeItems($value);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
removeItems($arr);
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/653780).

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 109
            [text] => dashboard
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [text] => financial_dashboard
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 108
                            [text] => project_dashboard
                        )

                )

        )

)
```